# How to setup VS2015 developer shell for cygwin emacs?

Tags: microsoft-windows, cygwin

I have cygwin emacs running on a machine with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 installed. I would like (for a number of reasons) to set it up as a shell, so that i would be able to run its developer commands from inside emacs

As far as i know, in previous Visual Studio versions, there were a number of environment variables set up in a  scenario file, which could be replicated in emacs configuration. However, in Visual Studio 2015, shell is being launched just as executable with a certain flag passed (in my case, one for 64 bit).

So, how can i go about that?